# Visual Studio 2012 | 2015 Indent Buttons

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Just moved from 2010 to 2012 at work.  I've played around with 2012 but am trying to get used to it.

Does anyone know what became of the left and right indent buttons in VS 2012, driving me crazy : z.  I've tried like all of the toolbar available.  In 2010 there are two buttons:

[image]

I know this has to be somewhere ?

Comment: Those buttons have really easy keyboard shotcuts. "Tab" for indenting to the right and "Shift+Tab" for indenting to the left.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yeah, if you have the HTML Source editing tool bar up then click the little down arrow on the right in that bar and you should be able to select those indents from there.

Comment: Why would they even put those there. Sometimes I wonder who designs these things. Like the new Comment/Uncomment buttons. thehell?! Anyways, thanks

Comment: while this so answer is helpful, the Microsoft decision-making process is really absurd; why remove these from where they belong?

Comment: I can't find it.  I loaded the microsoft sample chart project and it re-arranged my toolbars and eliminated indenting.  I have VS2010 VS Express and can't restore the settings.  Besides missing indenting the restart command is missing as well.